# Issue with FaultException`1' - Cannot specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, faultexception

I'm working on a C# application for merging duplicate Accounts in Dynamics CRM. In it I have checks on each of the fields that are part of the merge. It had been executing correctly, but then I ran into an instance where a lookup on the target record was not populated.

The check is written like this:

```
  if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_membership") 
      && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_membership"))
  {
      updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_membership", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_membership"]);
  }
```

I can see that the attribute is being returned correctly for the subOrdinateAccount, and the if does not return an error. However, later on in the code an exception is thrown. This is the line:

```
MergeResponse mergeRes = (MergeResponse)xrm.Execute(merge);
```

This is the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll Additional information: Cannot
>   specify child attributes in the columnset for Retrieve. Attribute:
>   new_membershipname

One thing I noticed is that it added "name" to the end of the lookup field.

Is this because it is looking for a different text value, rather than the returned object value?

*Here is the full code :*

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Xrm;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;
using System.Threading;

namespace Duplicate_Account_Merge
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XrmServiceContext xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm");
        Guid masterAccountId;
        Guid subOrdinateAccountId;


        //Create the target for the request.        
        EntityReference target = new EntityReference();


        // Query for Accounts


        var accounts = (from a in xrm.AccountSet.ToList()
                        where a.StateCode != 1 && a.Name != null
                        group a by a.Name into g
                        where g.Count() > 1
                        from a2 in xrm.AccountSet.ToList()
                        where a2.StateCode != 1
                        where a2.Name == g.Key
                        orderby a2.Name, a2.CreatedOn descending
                        select new
                        {
                            a2.Name,
                            //a2.LastName,
                            //a2.EMailAddress1,
                            a2.AccountId,
                            a2.CreatedOn
                        }).ToList();

        int count = 0;
        int mergeCount = 0;

        while (accounts.Count != 0 && accounts.Count != 1)
        {

            if (accounts.Count > 1 && accounts[0].Name == accounts[1].Name)
            {

                masterAccountId = accounts[0].AccountId.Value;
                subOrdinateAccountId = accounts[1].AccountId.Value;



                //target,Id is the GUID of the contact that is being merged into.        
                //LogicalName is the type of the entity being merged to, as a string        
                target.Id = masterAccountId;
                target.LogicalName = "account";

                //Create the request.        
                MergeRequest merge = new MergeRequest();



                // SubordinateId is the GUID of the contact merging.    
                merge.SubordinateId = subOrdinateAccountId;
                merge.Target = target;
                merge.PerformParentingChecks = false;
                Entity updateContent = new Entity("account");


                var accountcolumnset = new ColumnSet(
                    "name",
                    "accountnumber",
                    "new_membership",
                    //"parentaccountid",
                    "new_acronym",
                    "new_category",
                    "new_sortname",
                    "new_membertype",
                    "new_foundationtype",
                    "new_focusarea",
                    "new_focusarea2",
                    "new_focusarea3",
                    "new_100aging",
                    "new_isamember",
                    // Contacts section
                    "new_grantscontact",
                    "new_membershipcontact",
                    "msa_managingpartnerid",
                    "primarycontactid",
                    // Contact Information section
                    "address1_name",
                    "address1_composite",
                    "telephone1",
                    "websiteurl",
                    "emailaddress1",
                    // Details tab
                    // Contact Preferences section 
                    "preferredcontactmethodcode",
                    "donotphone",
                    "donotpostalmail",
                    // Marketing section
                    "donotsendmm",
                    "lastusedincampaign",
                    // Description section
                    "description"
                    );

                // Get Master Account Primary Contact,Website,Phone,Fax,Email
                Entity masterAccount = xrm.Retrieve("account", masterAccountId, accountcolumnset);

                // Get Subordinate Account Primary Contact,Website,Phone,Fax,Email
                Entity subOrdinateAccount = xrm.Retrieve("account", subOrdinateAccountId, accountcolumnset);

                // UPDATE THESE IFS WITH FIELD VALUES FROM THE COLUMN SET


                // If these fields are populated on the Subordinate Account and NOT populated on the Master Account, update the Master record with values from the suboordinate.  

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("accountnumber") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("accountnumber")) 
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("accountnumber", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["accountnumber"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_membership") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_membership"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_membership", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_membership"]);

                //updateContent.Attributes.Add("primarycontactid", new EntityReference("contact", subOrdinateContact.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("primarycontactid").Id));

                //if (!masterAccount.Contains("parentaccountid") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("parentaccountid"))
                //    updateContent.Attributes.Add("parentaccountid", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["parentaccountid"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_acronym") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_acronym"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_acronym", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_acronym"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_category") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_category"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_category", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_category"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_sortname") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_sortname"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_sortname", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_sortname"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_membertype") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_membertype"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_membertype", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_membertype"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_foundationtype") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_foundationtype"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_foundationtype", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_foundationtype"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_focusarea") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_focusarea"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_focusarea", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_focusarea"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_focusarea2") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_focusarea2"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_focusarea2", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_focusarea2"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_focusarea3") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_focusarea3"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_focusarea3", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_focusarea3"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_100aging") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_100aging"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_100aging", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_100aging"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_isamember") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_isamember"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_isamember", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_isamember"]);

                // Contact Information section

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("address1_name") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("address1_name"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("address1_name", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["address1_name"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("address1_composite") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("address1_composite"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("address1_composite", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["address1_composite"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("telephone1") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("telephone1"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("telephone1", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["telephone1"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("websiteurl") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("websiteurl"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("websiteurl", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["websiteurl"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("emailaddress1") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("emailaddress1"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("emailaddress1", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["emailaddress1"]);

                // Details tab 

                // Contact Preferences section

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("preferredcontactmethodcode") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("preferredcontactmethodcode"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("preferredcontactmethodcode", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["preferredcontactmethodcode"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("donotphone") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("donotphone"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("donotphone", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["donotphone"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("donotpostalmail") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("donotpostalmail"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("donotpostalmail", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["donotpostalmail"]);

                // Marketing section 

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("donotsendmm") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("donotsendmm"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("donotsendmm", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["donotsendmm"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("emailaddress1") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("emailaddress1"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("emailaddress1", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["emailaddress1"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("fax") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("fax"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("fax", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["fax"]);

                // Description section

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("preferredcontactmethodcode") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("preferredcontactmethodcode"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("preferredcontactmethodcode", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["preferredcontactmethodcode"]);

                // Contacts section 

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_grantscontact") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_grantscontact"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_grantscontact", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_grantscontact"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("new_membershipcontact") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("new_membershipcontact"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_membershipcontact", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_membershipcontact"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("msa_managingpartnerid") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("msa_managingpartnerid"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("msa_managingpartnerid", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["msa_managingpartnerid"]);

                if (!masterAccount.Contains("primarycontactid") && subOrdinateAccount.Contains("primarycontactid"))
                    updateContent.Attributes.Add("primarycontactid", subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["primarycontactid"]);



                merge.UpdateContent = updateContent;


                // Execute the request.   
                MergeResponse mergeRes = (MergeResponse)xrm.Execute(merge);

                count++;
                mergeCount++;

                Console.WriteLine("Merge #"
                    + mergeCount
                    + "\n" 
                    + "Master Account: " 
                    + accounts[0].Name
                    + " " 
                    + accounts[0].AccountId 
                    + "\n" 
                    + "Child Account: "
                    + accounts[1].Name
                    + " " 
                    + accounts[1].AccountId);



                accounts.RemoveAt(1);
            }
            else
            {

                if (accounts.Count > 2 && accounts.Count != 1 && accounts.Count != 0) 

                    accounts.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Provide full version of your code, please.

Comment: @AndriiButenko Okay I've updated it with a full version.

Comment: Your code looks good so I'm pretty sure that Early Bound is somehow related to your issue. Its just a suggestion - try to remove all the references from Context, Early Bound entities e.t.c. Try to use Entity/IOrganizationService and that should work properly.

Comment: Make sure you give an `EntityReference` object to the `updateContent.Attributes.Add()` method for `new_membership` attribute. You could also try explicitly giving in the name; something like `updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_membershipname", ((EntityReference)subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_membership"]).Name);`

Comment: @Seçkin Thank you! That was the answer!

Comment: You're welcome, i'll add my answer so you can approve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you give an `EntityReference` object to the `updateContent.Attributes.Add()` method for `new_membership` attribute.

You could also try explicitly giving in the name; something like

```
updateContent.Attributes.Add("new_membershipname", ((EntityReference)subOrdinateAccount.Attributes["new_membership"]).Name);
```